# React: How to provide procedurally generated <li> elements distinct HTML id values?

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm rendering a map of items retrieved from a database and filtered via the value state of an input field and attempting to then set the state of the input field as the value stored in some list item on click. I figured that using `document.getElementById().innerHTML` would allow me to retrieve the content stored within the appropriate tag and then set it to state which does work, the issue I'm facing is that it will only retrieve the innerHTML of the first item rendered in the map.

I've tried solutions ranging from applying UUID to making the mapped content available to the window and transfering the state of the individual objects but each disparate solution only moves the value of the first item to state - any ideas?

**Rendered Content:**

```
 window.filteredItems = this.state.items.filter(
  (item) => {
    return item.companyNameObj.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
  }
);

<div className="fixed-width">
  <div className="search-container">
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="search" className="search-bar" placeholder="Search: " onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.search} />
    </form>
      <ul className="search-results">
        {window.filteredItems.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div className="distinct-result-container">
              <li key={item.id}>
                <div className="image-container">
                  <img src={item.imageObj} alt={item.companyNameObj + " logo."}/>
                </div>
                <div className="company-container">
                  <span onClick={this.stateTransfer}><h3 id={"ID"}>{item.companyNameObj}</h3></span>
                  <p>Owned by: {item.ownerNameObj}</p>
                </div>
              </li>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </div>
);
```

**stateTransfer()**

```
stateTransfer(id) {
  var search = this.state.search;
  var uniqueID = document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML;

  this.setState({
    search: uniqueID
  });
}
```

The current content of stateTransfer() doesn't represent any significant attempts at approaching a solution to this issue, it's just the minimum required implementation to move the innerHTML content to the input fields value.

**EDIT:** I've further clarified on the task at hand and a potential solution in the comments below (which follow this), I'm just hoping someone is able to help me with the actual implementation.

> @DILEEPTHOMAS The list is comprised of data pulled from a Firebase Realtime Database and is rendered via mapping the filteredList and a search query; that functoionality works fine - what I need is to be able to click the  element of any distinct li and have the innerHTML (the text stored in that li's item.companyNameObj) be moved to the value of the input field (so users can navigate the search content with re-typing).
>
> @JoshuaLink I can't necessarily configure the items of the list any
>   further as it's just data pulled from an external database - I believe
>   the appropriate solution is to somehow provide a unique HTML ID value
>   to each newly rendered li and have that selected ID moved to
>   stateTransfer() where it can be set as the input fields value, I'm
>   just struggling with the actual implementation of this.

**EDIT 2:** I've managed to figure out a solution to both parts of the problem as described above - I'll post it as an answer below.

Comment: What about adding an ID to the list and changing the innerHTML of the list? you can just configure your list items how you want and then set all those items as the inner html for your list. If that doesn't help you, please explain better what you want to do and what the problem is.:)

Comment: what i understood is you have a list that gets from a rest service, now you need to render the list based on the input field. thats y you are doing a filter based on the input after that the filtered list should be rendered. It will be easy if you can explain further on this

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS The list is comprised of data pulled from a Firebase Realtime Database and is rendered via mapping the filteredList and a search query; that functoionality works fine - what I need is to be able to click the <H3> element of any distinct <li> and have the innerHTML (the text stored in that <li>'s item.companyNameObj) to be moved to the value of the input field (so users can navigate the search content with re-typing).

Comment: @JoshuaLink I can't necessarily configure the items of the list any further as it's just data pulled from an external database - I believe the appropriate solution is to somehow provide a unique HTML ID value to each newly rendered <li> and have that selected ID moved to stateTransfer() where it can be set as the input fields value, I'm just struggling with the actual implementation of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve both parts of my problem:

The key issue, which was moving the text stored in each distinct li to the input value, which was apparently easily solved by making my stateTransfer() function accept an event and passing the .innerText value of the h3 through the event (I assumed I would have to use .innerHTML, which would require me to provide each distinct li with a unique generated ID) as follows:

```
stateTransfer(e) {
  var search = this.state.search;
  var innerText = e.target.innerText

  this.setState({
    search: innerText
  })
}
```

The secondary issue, (which I incorrectly assumed was integral to implementing a solution to my question), assigning unique HTML id values to my procedurally generated li's was solved by implementing a for-loop in a componentDidUpdate() function which iterates through the current total length of the list and and assigns an id with the loop iterator concatenated to the end of the string as follows:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  var i;
  var searchCompanyNames = document.querySelectorAll('.comapnyNames');

  for(i = 0; i < searchCompanyNames.length; i++) {
    searchCompanyNames[i].id = 'companyName-' + i;
  }
}
```

Whilst I didn't need to assign unique ID's to the li's in the correct implementation, it's a useful trick worth noting nonetheless.